# Regarding PGA bypass in ADS1262

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, analogread

I want to bypass the PGA to change the input signal range from +/-2.5 to 0/5 V range.

I have taken the reference of example given in [this](https://github.com/Protocentral/ProtoCentral_ads1262) library.

I have interfaced [protocentral-ads1262-32-bit-precision-adc-breakout-board](https://www.protocentral.com/analog-adc-boards/1005-protocentral-ads1262-32-bit-precision-adc-breakout-board-0642078949630.html) with Arduino Ethernet Board.

In the example, I have put `#define VREF 5` but it shows the double the input voltage in serial window and when I put `VREF 2.5`, it shows regular input voltage.

For input voltage range 0 to 5V (single signal), I need to bypass the PGA but I dont know how to do it.

When the input signal is more than 2.5V then it always give the 2.5V only. If the input signal is, say 4.86V then it should give 4.86V but its gives 2.5V.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to bypass the PGA.

By default the chip uses the 2.5v internal reference. You need to switch that to using AVDD/AVSS as the voltage reference. If the library doesn't allow that you will have to do it manually referring to the datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to bypass the PGA to change the input signal range from +/-2.5 to 0/5 V range.

Look at the register map. it should allow you to by pass the pga.

> In the example, I have put #define VREF 5 but it shows the double the input voltage in serial window and when I put VREF 2.5, it shows regular input voltage.

Simple solution: divide the library's output by 2.

Right solution: the library likely doesn't support bipolar output. So re-write  your own.